# virtual copy (in memory) of a directory structure?

Tags: python, virtualization

I am using an iPython interface to a software package. Due to limitations in the latter, a LOT of disk I/O is required: built-in functions manipulate the files on disk (stored as various files in a directory), from which I then read the results with other built-in functions.

Can I create a "virtual copy" of a whole directory structure, which is completely held in memory? I have checked the tempfile library, but this does not seem to handle whole directories. shutil just makes a copy of the full directory to disk, which is not what I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'virtual copy', can you clarify exactly how you want this copy to behave? You might want to look at making a "RAM disk" but the details of that are probably beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: what I want is something that behaves just like the directory structure on disk, but which is held in memory and does not require disk I/O (the latter is slowing down the code)

Comment: Then you probably want to look at making a RAM disk and copying all the files you're working on to that before running the rest of the code.

Comment: googling "RAM disk", I can see that you are probably on target. Thanks!